# How to express a business logic rule in domain model if that rule should be implemented in persistence layer?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I'm currently learning DDD and it seems that I misunderstand some core ideas there.
Let's say there is an "A" aggregate. It references several other entities and value objects. It is impossible (not on purpose) to create or change it programmatically so it would become invalid. "A" can be created via constructor. An existing aggregate can be changed.

```cs
public class A : IEntity {
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public B B { get; }
    public C C { get; }

    public A(string name, B b)
    {
        Name = name;
        B = b;
        // Some validation logic here to ensure that Name and B properties are correct. 
        // Throw an exception if business rules are not satisfied.
    }

    public void Edit(string newName, B newB)
    {
        // Some validation logic here to ensure that the aggregate with new values is correct.
        Name = newName;
        B = newB;
    }

}
```

There is also a "C" aggragate. It is referenced by "A". It cannot be created without one "A" (one-to-one relationship). It also contains some "D" entities (one-to-many).

```cs
public class D: IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; }
}

public class C: IEntity
{
    private readonly List<D> _ds = new List<D>();
    public int Id { get; }
    public IReadOnlyCollection<D> Ds => _ds;

    public void AddD(D d)
    {
        // Some validation logic for adding here.
        _ds.Add(d);
    }
}
```

So now I would like to introduce a new business rule: we can edit "A" only if it doesn't have "C" or its "C" does not have any "D"s. The naive implementation is very simple:

```cs
public class A : IEntity 
{
   // just add this new method:
   public bool CanEdit() => C == null || !C.Ds.Any(); 

   // also invoke the above method in Edit() and throw if it's false.
}
```

However, this approach is definitely going to "bite" me later. At the "let's just have a look at "A"s" use-case I don't need to load any "C"s or "D"s in my application. However, I need to know if I can edit these "A" entities. So the actual implementation of this rule should appear in the persistance layer.

How can I express such a rule in my domain model code and implement it in the persistance layer? Should I place it in repositories or domain services? Maybe it's better to use CQRS-style queries? Or is it just easier for everyone to have a comment that explains what rule should be implemented in the persistance layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is a problem that you should not have in the first place. Your Aggregates should not have direct references to other aggregates. When you hear that an Aggregate can reference another Aggregate, it only means that it can store the other aggregate's Id, not the whole aggregate. Therefore, you should never have Aggregate A with properties of type B and C. Instead, you'd have properties with the Ids of aggregates B and C.

By removing this problem from your aggregates you remove your main problem, but you get a new one: How do you actually check that business rule in aggregate A which depends on aggregate C?

This is impossible to answer without discussing the details about the real domain. But consider the following two options:

1. Your aggregates are wrong. This is the first thing you should consider when you have business rules that span multiple aggregates. Why does this happen in the first place? Maybe they should be a single aggregate, or maybe part of C belongs to A. The point of aggregates is to encapsulate business rules and the data they need to be evaluated. If an aggregate doesn't have the data it needs then there is something wrong in its design.
2. Your aggregates are correct, but A needs to know something about C. This happens very often. A takes care of Discounts and C takes care of UserLoyalty. We want to give 10% discount if the user becomes Premium by having more than 1000 points. Following your approach, A could reference C and look at the user points. But instead, it's a better design to let C encapsulate the logic that makes a user become Premium. So, C will track the user points. At some point, it will decide that the user has become Premium and it will raise a UserBecamePremiumEvent. Aggregate A will receive that event and store IsPremium in its data. During the next purchase, A will do "If user IsPremium, apply 10% discount".